# Oracle SQLDeveloper Autocomplete in Lowercase (How about Uppercase)

Tags: oracle, autocomplete, uppercase, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently using the latest Oracle sql developer. I just have one nuisance here. When I do auto-complete of table names or columns, they show up in lower case. As most people I do have coding guidelines in SQL statements and I usually want table names, column names, and any other identifiers in all capitals.

I tried to check the settings in sql developer and the "Code Insight" section does not have any option for this. Is there any other tweak for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using SQL Developer 2.1 (EA) from http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index21_EA1.html

.. which IMHO is much better than the 'current' version that I believe you're using. In the 2.1 version you can goto Tools > Preferences > Database > SQL Formatter > Oracle Formatting and hit 'Edit' to alter the behaviour of capitalisation effects.

It is my understanding, however, that in a Worksheet this will not 'autoformat' .. it only does this in procedures, packages, views, and triggers. (So you'll have to highligh, right-click, Format to do this in a worksheet).

Comment: I set the "Other" > "Case change" settings to "Whole SQL Uppercase" and it worked. Thanks pierre. I am also beginning to love this early adopter version because the "Format" command only highlights selection unlike version 1.5.5 that highlights the whole file.

Comment: version >= 19.1.0.x, you can adjust upper-/lower-case identifiers and keywords in Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Format

Answer (score 30):

I'm using SQL Developer 3.1.07 and you can change the case of the autocompleted table names by going to Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Completion Insight there is an option for 'Change case as you type'.

Answer (score 7):

For those using SQL Developer version 19.1.0.x, you can adjust upper-/lower-case identifiers and keywords in 
Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Format

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SQL Developer 4.0.3.16 My Requirement is to see everything in uppercase while typing.

Tried the below setting but didn't notice any change happening.
Tools > Preferences > Database > SQL Formatter > Oracle Formatting and hit 'Edit' to alter the behaviour of capitalisation effects.

Tried the below setting and I'm able to see some change happening. This setting do not convert the text to uppercase as when we type but when we hit 'Enter' button, all text will change to uppercase.
Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Completion Insight > 'Change case as you type' to 'Upper Case'.

Hope this helps!